# Is there a variable that keeps track of which pages are enabled or disabled in Page Manager?

Tags: features, configuration, strongarm

I'm using the Features module and I'm tired of manually enabling/disabling pages (user_edit, user_view, etc.)  Is there a variable that I can add to Strongarm to control this in code?

Comment: Where have you looked already? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a variable per page of the form "page_manager_MACHINE_NAME_disabled", eg. "page_manager_node_view_disabled". You need to set it to FALSE using Strongarm to enable the corresponding page.